# Save custom field value from the quote table to sales order table

Tags: event-observer, magento2.2.4

I am facing a problem to save custom field value from the **quote table** to **sales order** table. I have the custom field in quote table and sales order table, but the value is not saving in the sales order table. I am using observer with “`sales_order_place_before`” and here is my code

```
namespace Tristar\AffiliateCode\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory;
class Placeorder implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $_logger;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $quoteFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     */

    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
                               \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->quoteFactory =   $quoteFactory;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        $quoteId = $order->getQuoteId();
        $quote  =   $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quoteId);
        $affileatevalue =   $quote->getAffiliateCode();        
        $order->setAffiliateCode($quote->getAffiliateCode());
        $order->save();
    }
}
```

Here is my event.xml file and the file location is "etc/frontend/"

```
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
    <observer name="tristar_affiliate_code" instance="Tristar\AffiliateCode\Observer\AddToCartAfter"/>
</event>
<event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
    <observer name="tristar_affiliate_code_order_place_before_action" instance="Tristar\AffiliateCode\Observer\PlaceOrder"/>
</event>
```

Comment: is it `event.xml` or `events.xml`? if it is `event.xml` then rename to `events.xml`

Comment: It's events.xml

Comment: do as @amitebera suggest

Comment: change your class name from `Placeorder` to `PlaceOrder` or change  class name in xml file.

Comment: @RakeshVarma - I already change the class name to PlaceOrder. what you meant by change the class name in xml file ?

Comment: its okay if you change class name in observer file

Answer (score 1):

instead of `sales_order_place_before` event use `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` event and below code in your observer

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        $quoteId = $order->getQuoteId();
        $quote  =   $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quoteId);
        $affileatevalue =   $quote->getAffiliateCode();        
        $order->setAffiliateCode($quote->getAffiliateCode());
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but still not working

Comment: Check if you are getting value from quote object or for testing set any value in it . If possible add your events.xml file location and XML code in question

Comment: I added the events.xml and location to the question

Comment: Looks like this is a bug in Magento 2.2.6 because the same event is triggering in 2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before`  at frontend  area in eventts.xml.

You have to defined at global scope. Means you have to create `events.xml` at `app\code\{Vendorname}\{Modulename}\etc\` as Magento checkout page  is Magento api means Rest API area.

Comment: I tried your method but no luck, i tried with "die" to check my observer is firing or not and it's not. I am not sure what i am missing.

Comment: can you please help